# Erratic Gaps between elements

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website for a friend and it's quite image heavy, I've sliced up the image into relevant bits but I've deciding to use divs and not make use of tables. So this is what I've got:

The Html

```
<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="header">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/header1280.jpg" /></a>
</div><!--end header-->

<div id="nav">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/mixes.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/events.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/artists.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/christ.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/links.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/contact.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/hos.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/forum.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/news.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fun.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/shop.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/join.jpg" /></a></li> 
    </ul>

</div><!--end nav-->

</div><!--end container--> 

</body>
```

The CSS

```
html, body, div, img, ul, li, a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0px none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background: #000;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
}
#nav ul li a img {
    width: 100%
    height: auto;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;   
    width: 100%;
}
#nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

Now there are 12 image links in all and they span over 2 lines. So imagine You have this:

HEADER
NAV LINE 1
NAV LINE 2

on Chrome a 2px gap is created between the header & the NavLine1 & between Navline1 & Navline2. This can be eliminated by:

```
li {margin-top: -2px;}
```

On firefox 3.6 there is instead a 3px gap between the Header & Navline1 & just a 2px gap between NavLine1 % Navline 2.

On IE8 there is instead a 2px gap between the Header and Navline1 but a 3px gap between Navline1 and Navline2.

I'm a little confused as to whats causing this, is it a float bug? But can anyone shed some light on the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#header img, #nav img {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

`img` elements are `inline` with a default `vertical-align` of `baseline`. The problematic gap is the space reserved for descenders in letters like `g` or `p`. Changing `vertical-align` from `baseline` removes the gap.

Comment: Oh that's what was causing it. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, sorry it took so long, I took a very long break.